# TYPO3 DBAL Querybuilder: Nested SELECT statements?

Tags: typo3, greatest-n-per-group, query-builder

Is it possible to build nested SELECT statements like the one below using the DBAL QueryBuilder?

```
SELECT i.id, i.stable_id, i.version, i.title
FROM initiatives AS i
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT stable_id, MAX(version) AS max_version FROM initiatives GROUP BY stable_id
) AS tbl1
ON i.stable_id = tbl1.stable_id AND i.version = tbl1.max_version
ORDER BY i.stable_id ASC
```

The goal is to query an external non TYPO3 table which contains different versions of each data set. Only the data set with the highest version number should be rendered. The database looks like this:

id, stable_id, version, [rest of the data row]

`stable_id` is the external id of the data set. `id` is the internal autoincrement id. And `version` is also incremented automatically.

Code example:

```
$queryBuilder = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(ConnectionPool::class)->getQueryBuilderForTable($this->table);
$result = $queryBuilder
    ->select(...$this->select)
    ->from($this->table)
    ->join(
        'initiatives',
        $queryBuilder
            ->select('stable_id, MAX(version) AS max_version' )
            ->from('initiatives')
            ->groupBy('stable_id'),
        'tbl1',
        $queryBuilder->and(
            $queryBuilder->expr()->eq(
                'initiatives.stable_id',
                $queryBuilder->quoteIdentifier('tbl1.stable_id')
            ),
            $queryBuilder->expr()->eq(
                'initiatives.version',
                $queryBuilder->quoteIdentifier('tbl1.max_version')
            )
        )
    )
    ->orderBy('stable_id', 'DESC')
```

I cannot figure out the correct syntax for the ON ... AND statement. Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: it is not possible because the table to be joined in is generated on the fly. The related expression is back-ticked and thus causes an SQL error.

But: The SQL query can be changed to the following SQL query which does basically the same:

```
SELECT i1.id,stable_id, version, title, p.name, l.name, s.name
FROM initiatives i1
WHERE version = (
    SELECT MAX(i2.version)
    FROM initiatives i2
    WHERE i1.stable_id = i2.stable_id
)
ORDER BY stable_id ASC
```

And this can be rebuild with the DBAL queryBuilder:

```
$queryBuilder = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(ConnectionPool::class)->getQueryBuilderForTable($this->table);
$result = $queryBuilder
    ->select(...$this->select)
    ->from($this->table)
    ->where(
        $queryBuilder->expr()->eq(
            'initiatives.version',
            '(SELECT MAX(i2.version) FROM initiatives i2 WHERE initiatives.stable_id = i2.stable_id)'
        ),
    ->orderBy('stable_id', 'DESC')
    ->setMaxResults( 50 )
    ->execute();
```

Answer (score 1):

Extbase queries have `JOIN` capabilities but are otherwise very limited. You could use custom SQL (see `->statement()` [here](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/book-extbasefluid/master/en-us/6-Persistence/3-implement-individual-database-queries.html)), though.

A better API to build complex queries is the [(Doctrine DBAL) QueryBuilder](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/master/en-us/ApiOverview/Database/QueryBuilder/Index.html), including support for `JOINs`, database functions like `MAX()` and raw expressions (`->addSelectLiteral()`). Make sure to read until the [ExpressionBuilder](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/master/en-us/ApiOverview/Database/ExpressionBuilder/Index.html) where it gets interesting.

So Extbase queries are useful in order to retrieve Extbase (model) objects. It can make implicit use of its knowledge of your data structure in order to save you some code but only supports rather simple queries.

The (Doctrine DBAL) QueryBuilder fulfills all other needs. If needed, you can convert the raw data to Extbase models, too. ([for example](https://github.com/TYPO3/TYPO3.CMS/blob/master/typo3/sysext/extbase/Classes/Property/PropertyMapper.php#L115) `$propertyMapper->convert($data, Job::class)`).

I realize that we lack clear distinguishing between the two because they were both known at some time as "QueryBuilder", but they are totally different. That's why I like to add "Doctrine" when referring to the non-Extbase one.

An example with a `JOIN ON` multiple criteria.

```
$q = TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::makeInstance(TYPO3\CMS\Core\Database\ConnectionPool::class)
    ->getQueryBuilderForTable('fe_users');

$res = $q->select('*')
    ->from('tt_content', 'c')
    ->join(
        'c',
        'be_users',
        'bu',
        $q->expr()->andX(
            $q->expr()->eq(
                'c.cruser_id', $q->quoteIdentifier('bu.uid')
            ),
            $q->expr()->comparison(
                '2', '=', '2'
            )
        )
    )
    ->setMaxResults(5)
    ->execute()
    ->fetchAllAssociative();
```

Comment: Sorry, my fault. I actually wanted to use the DBAL query builder. I also tried already with property mapping but couldn't succeed because of the non TYPO3 conform data structure of the external table.

Comment: I have added a non-working code example with DBAL expression builder.

Comment: What's the error you get when running your code?

Comment: `Call to undefined method`. I tried different syntax: $queryBuilder->and(), $queryBuilder->logicalAnd(), $queryBuilder->expr()->and(), $queryBuilder->expr()->logicalAnd(), but without success. A look into the source seems to show that there is no possibility for `JOIN .... ON ( ... AND ...)` statements via the DBAL querybuilder. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, that's possible.
`    ->join(
        'c',
        'be_users',
        'bu',
        $q->expr()->andX(
            $q->expr()->eq(
                'c.cruser_id', $q->quoteIdentifier('bu.uid')
            ),
            $q->expr()->comparison(
                '2', '=', '2'
            )
        )
    )`

Comment: I've added the example to my answer.

Comment: Nice, thank you. But now the next problem shows up. As you can see I create the joined table on the fly with the queryBuilder. This throws an error message: `The given alias 'tbl1' is not unique in FROM and JOIN clause table. The currently registered aliases are: 'initiatives
, 'tbl1'.`

Comment: Yes, you are right. There is no way to use a `SELECT` statement for a joined table. I think it is the only place I found where it is not possible to use non-escaped (raw) SQL, too. Glad that you managed by refactoring. I find myself using `$q->selectLiteral()` or abusing unescaped conditions (by using plain strings instead of `$q->expr()->`) for low-level SQL. We should be wary that we lose cross-DBMS capability by doing that.